# Unsafe legacy lifecycles will not be called for components using new component APIs. React v16.3

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure what I do wrong:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return {};
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I get this error with React v16.3:

> warning.js:33 Warning: Unsafe legacy lifecycles will not be called for
>   components using new component APIs.
>
> Test uses getDerivedStateFromProps() but also contains the following
>   legacy lifecycles:   componentWillReceiveProps
>
> The above lifecycles should be removed. Learn more about this warning
>   here:

But it doesn't contain `componentWillReceiveProps`...

Comment: Do you also use react-hot-loader? If so, https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/918 should be the source of the bug.

Comment: @Iso yes I do. Thanks! I didn't knew about it.

Comment: @Iso you should post this as an answer so it can be marked as such in SO :) it was a great catch

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.